# RmGetList consistently returning 0x5 ERROR_ACCESS_DNIED

Tags: winapi

I am getting consistently a return value of `5` from `RmGetList`, any possible reasons?

I am following this tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/17/10268840.aspx

My `RmStartSession` and `RmRegstierResources` both return `0` which means success. A note though, after RmStartSession the `dwSession` is always 0, and my `szSessionKey` stays a string in the form of `0ea790d06656a54f84645b5755f7b6d6` null terminated. Is this a problem?

My code is js-ctypes so I'm reluctant to share this in winapi but ill share it: https://github.com/Noitidart/_scratchpad/blob/master/_WinAPI-RstrtMgr.js#L293

Edit: I learned that dwSession of 0 is a valid. However I still can't figure out why I'm getting access denied on RmGetList, anyone any ideas?

Comment: Your process token doesn't have sufficient rights? What does it need? What does it have?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks, I actually was mistaken, my szSessionKey succesfully coming back as a string like `0ea790d06656a54f84645b5755f7b6d6` i cant explain it. how to test what my process token rights are please?

Comment: I'm sure my process token as the rights, because the same RstrMgr technique is done by core of my software (Firefox), im doing it from addon. This is the core doing same thing: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/profile/dirserviceprovider/ProfileUnlockerWin.cpp#152

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I past in just the file name rather then the full file path and its not throwing that error, but its weird i need to pass in file path because I have multiple `parent.lock` files open i need to know of a specific `parent.lock` file in a specific folder, is that possible? Also a note, if i use just file name im getting to results in affect processes array :(

Comment: Anyone any ideas im totaly stuck I can't figure this one out :(

Comment: @Noitidart Have you ever figured this out? Maybe you need to elevate the process that calls the API? Error 5 is ACCESS DENIED.

Comment: Hey @KirillOsenkov yep I figured it out, here is my work in js-ctypes - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/6203ba1b410b7bacaa82 - I can't remember what the issue was, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

I've learned that the restart manager doesn't support folders, and the error 5 is returned when you're trying to pass a folder:
https://blog.yaakov.online/failed-experiment-what-processes-have-a-lock-on-this-folder/

**Update:** here's some sample code of how to use the restart manager API:
https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/Tasks/LockCheck.cs

Comment: Ah very interesting. I was passing a file, I can't recall what was causing it, but I know I fixed it in my code here - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/6203ba1b410b7bacaa82 - In the end though, I ended up using `NtQuerySystemInformation` and `NtQueryFileInformtion`, the restart manager wouldn't work well for me and and have lots of WinXP users.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have the code that uses NtQuerySystemInformation?

Comment: Yep I'll dig it out, if I don't get back to you in 24h please remind me.

Comment: @Noitidart I'd be very interested too, if you still have it around!

Comment: @jnm2 here is my code that works - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/6203ba1b410b7bacaa82#file-_ff-addon-snippet-winapi_rstrtmgr-js-L301 - it is in js-ctypes.

Comment: @Noitidart Sorry, I meant the code that uses NtQuerySystemInformation that Kirill asks about a few comments up.

Comment: @jnm2 I have some gists about that too: (1) https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/4a14050cd0baf0ab91b8 (2) https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/d752e2c59793fa2cab3c (3) https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/ad025c76a34e84544856

Comment: @KirillOsenkov excuse the delay, but you can see the gists above.

Answer (score 2):

RmGetList will return error 5 if any higher level thing like a file system fillter block the file 
the driver filter denies access to file xxx from any process and function whether windows kernel or user code tries to access it 
it does the same with restart manager , restart manger tries to access the file , the driver throws error 5 , the restart manager wont know what to do with it ,and rethrows it back to calling function ,so you'll get a access denied

if you are trying it for all files in windows volume, there will be much files with throwing error 5, including 3rd parity antivirus files or ms defender  or ...

simply use a try catch and ignore them because even if you know what pid is locking them you couldn't do anything about it, other than watching

it also happens if you don't have even read access to the locked file ,in this case try fixing security permotions and trying again